# Changing the unselected color of a UITabBar Item iOS 9

Tags: colors, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, ios9, uitabbaritem

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.'
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        UITabBar.appearance().selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } //method is in TabBarViewController
```

I would like the unselected color to be white and selected color to be red. The selectedImageTintColor property is deprecated in iOS 9, and I was wondering how I'd be able to change the unselected image color otherwise? Also, I was able to change the selected image tint color the red color in storyboard by changing the tabbar keypath's color attribute to red. I was wondering if there was a way of changing the unselected and selected color in storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your original image is displayed as white. Then you just tell the `TabBarItem` to render the unselected image as `.AlwaysOriginal` and the set a `selectedImage` on it like so:

```
let tabBarImage = UIImage(named: "icon-tab-name")
let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Title", image: tabBarImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal), selectedImage: tabBarImage)
```

And then have

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

This way you will have a **white unselected** state and a **red selected** state.

Answer (score 0):

I did with this peace of code in the viewDidLoad method:

```
self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in my description. I'd like to have the unselected white and the selected red. When I set the tint color to white (as with your code or variations), it has the selected as red but the unselected as white,

Comment: I solved a similar issue combining with the UIImage imageWithRenderingMode method. Just like this: `myImage.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change all of them in IOS 10, do something like this in the appDelegate. This is changing all the unselected ones to black.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

    return true
}
```